# How can I open the Black Door to the west of Falkreath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There is a black door to the west from Falkreath, when trying to open it a voice asks

> What is the music of life?

As I don't know the answer I can't get through that door. Where do I get the password to that door, which quest does this dungeon belong to?

[image]

Comment: There is another one on the coast of skyrim travel along until you reach it. It will ask what is life's greatest allusion? It is for a sanctuary. I forgot which one hold it's for though. I think it was dawnstar. Look for it , but becareful because bandits horkers snow bears and three thugs discused as impiral soilders are there also. Don't pay them say if you can take it from me. This will start combat becareful one has middle threat magic if you are lower than level 17 I would say. That's what I have got for now I will post if I find more

Comment: The one in Dawnstar is unlocked further down the quest line for the Dark Brotherhood.

Comment: you can destroy the dark brotherhood too, not need to join them! I cant post an answer for some reason... check [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destroy_the_Dark_Brotherhood!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the Dark Brotherhood's sanctuary.

To get through that door you have to

> kill the owner of the orphanage in Riften and then a courier brings you a note. Sleep to be contacted by them, then they will give you the necessary information to join from there.

They may not contact you the first time you sleep so keep trying, eventually they will.

Comment: Actually, there's a quest with this goal, to start this, you want to go to winterhold.

Comment: Technically, the quest can be said to start in Riften (or anywhere else there's an inn that will share the appropriate rumor, I suppose), but this answer is still missing the necessary step in Winterhold.

Comment: Windhelm, not Winterhold.

Answer (score 7):

Talk to the Inn Keeper in Riverwood and ask about any rumors he has heard.  He will talk to you about a person in Windhelm trying to contact the Dark Brotherhood.  After this you will have the quest line in your Misc. Quest Section.  Just follow the quest line from there.

Answer (score 5):

All of the other answers seem to have the basics down, but don't really cover the whole story.  Here's what needs to be done:

At some inns, you may hear rumors of a kid in Windhelm who's been trying to contact the Dark Brotherhood.  Alternatively, you can talk to any of the kids in the orphanage in Riften and they will tell you about their friend who ran away to Windhelm.  Perhaps one other "appropriate" way to start this quest would be to just break into the Aretino (as if you were just going to do a random burglary) residence in Windhelm and talk to Aventus there.

> All of the above paths eventually lead to you having a chat with Aventus Aretino at his late parents' house in Windhelm.  He'll mistake you for the answer to his prayers (a Dark Brotherhood assassin), and ask you to kill the owner of the orphanage in Riften.  Go kill her and report back to Aventus.

The shortest way to do this though, is to skip all of the above.

> Just go straight to the orphanage in Riften and kill Grelod The Kind.  Then go break into the Aretino residence (I don't think I've ever encountered it unlocked) in Windhelm and talk to Aventus.

After following either path above, eventually you should have a random courier approach you.

> He'll have a note that simply has a black hand-print, and the words "We know."

Once you've received your message, go home and go to sleep.  (You may be able to go straight home without receiving the message, but I'm guessing that is why some others are claiming that the quest won't start on your first sleep.)  Even one hour of sleep should be enough.

> You'll wake up in a strange shack where you're addressed by Astrid, the leader of the Dark Brotherhood and your captor for the moment.  She wants you to kill one of the three other people she's captured there.  Kill any or all of those three, and she'll invite you to join the Dark Brotherhood.

At this point, you'll receive the password to the Black Door.

Useful references:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Innocence_Lost
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:With_Friends_Like_These...

Comment: Windhelm, not Winterhold :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> This is the door to the Dark Brotherhood.
> "Silence, My Brother"

But this answer isnt available untill you have completed the questchain mentioned earlier

Answer (score -1):

go to windhelm and take a right then take the first left and there will be two people out side of a house a kid and a women go into the house and there will be a boy saying a chant "sweat mother , sweat mother send you child upon me for the sins of the unworthy must be baptised in blood and fear" talk to him and he will ask if you are from the dark brotherhood say yes then go through the other voice options the go to sleep and the brotherhood will kidnap you and thats the start of the questline

Answer (score -4):

You have to do "inoccence lost", then you sleep until they contact you. They will give you the  awnser.  I think you have to have the mace of molag bal. To get it, complete the house of horrors. and you get saviours hide complete I'll let moonlight.

Comment: you do not need the mace nor the savior's hide